# Jquery Ajax doesn't work in Firefox (used to work in previous versions) but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

This simple code works in Chrome (displays your IP) but not in Firefox returns the following error :

> "An error occured: 404 error".

```
<script>$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://freegeoip.net/json/",
        dataType: "JSONP", 
        error: function(xhr)
            {
            console.log("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }, 
        success: function(data)
            {
            console.log(data.ip);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ayo52Lx/5/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found my stupid mistake and maybe it will help others: My addblocker blocked the request.

Case solved.